# How to define forms in JSF primefaces with pe:layoutPane

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces

I have a template layout with JSF 2 and primefaces and primefaces extensions layoutPane. The left side has an search area and a structure are. The right side is a details area.
Here a short form of the template:

```
<html>
 <f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <pe:layout id="layoutId">
        <pe:layoutPane id="layoutPaneWestId" position="west" size="30%" closable="false" resizeWhileDragging="true">

            <pe:layoutPane id="layoutPaneSearchId" position="north" closable="false" resizable="false">
                <h:form id="searchForm">
                    <ui:insert name="search" />
                </h:form>
            </pe:layoutPane>

            <pe:layoutPane id="layoutPaneContentId" position="center">
                <h:form id="structureForm">
                    <ui:insert name="content" />
                </h:form>
            </pe:layoutPane>

        </pe:layoutPane>

        <pe:layoutPane id="layoutPaneDetailId" position="center" size="70%" closable="false">
            <h:form id="detailsForm">
                <ui:insert name="details" />
            </h:form>
        </pe:layoutPane>

    </pe:layout>

</h:body>
```

Each area has its own form. Now I ask myself what shall I do with the e. g. with a global p:growl. In which form should it be? Nested forms are invalid html as I know.
Another big problem is that when I type something in the search field in searchForm and click on an accordion panel in structureForm, the content of the search field is submitted. Why?

Kind regards
Oli

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `global p:growl` in another form outside `pe:layout`.

The second problem could be related to some update invoked from `structureForm` to `searchForm`

Comment: Thanks. I found it. I submitted the text entered in search with: 
<p:ajax event="change" update=":structureForm" process="@this" />

After I added a button for the submit it works:
<p:commandButton value="OK" process="clSearchTextId" update=":structureForm" />